# How do we compute this sum using indefinite integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Given that , $f\left( n \right)=\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{n}{\ln {{\left( \frac{6n+2k}{n} \right)}^{\frac{2}{6n+2k}}}}$.

How do we find the following limit  $\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,f\left( n \right)$

I tried first to use some appropriate definite integral to evaluate it.

I Tried to do the following:

$\begin{gathered}
{{=}\mathop{\sum}\nolimits_{{k}{=}{1}}\nolimits^{n}{\frac{2}{{6}{n}{+}{2}{k}}\ln\left({\frac{{6}{n}{+}{2}{k}}{n}}\right)}} \hfill\\
{{=}\mathop{\sum}\nolimits_{{k}{=}{1}}\nolimits^{n}{\frac{2}{{6}{n}\left({{1}{+}\frac{2k}{6n}}\right)}\ln\left({\frac{{6}{n}\left({{1}{+}\frac{2k}{6n}}\right)}{n}}\right)}} \hfill\\
{{=}\mathop{\sum}\nolimits_{{k}{=}{1}}\nolimits^{n}{\frac{1}{3n}\times\frac{1}{{1}{+}\frac{k}{3n}}\ln\left({{6}\left({{1}{+}\frac{k}{3n}}\right)}\right)}} \hfill\\
{{=}\frac{1}{3}\frac{{1}{-}{0}}{n}\mathop{\sum}\nolimits_{{k}{=}{1}}\nolimits^{n}{\frac{1}{{1}{+}\frac{k}{3n}}\left({\ln\left({6}\right){+}\ln\left({{1}{+}\frac{k}{3n}}\right)}\right)}} \hfill\\
 \hfill
\end{gathered}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$f(n) =2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(6+\frac{2k}{n} \right)}{6n+2k} =\frac 2n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(6+\frac{2k}{n}\right)}{6+\frac{2k}{n}}$$

Taking $x=\frac kn$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln(2x+6)}{2x+6} dx = \frac 12\left((\ln8)^2 - (\ln6)^2\right)$$